# Angular with mat-form doesn't compile: ngcc failed to run on parse5@5.1.1

Tags: angular, typescript, compiler-errors, angular-cli

I created a small `mat-form` example and I cannot tell you why the compile error is showing up or what's wrong, so cannot specify it here, please have a look here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2ummrb

The error showing up:

```
Error in ~/src/main.ts
ngcc failed to run on parse5@5.1.1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem with my StackBlitz project.

**Step 1.** In StackBlitz although you setup your project to enable or disable Ivy, you also have to enable or disable Ivy via the StackBlitz project settings too. You find that on the left side (Settings). If you did that do a page reload.

**Step 2.** If some dependencies' versions do not work together for StackBlitz (not supported from StackBlitz?), you'll get errors like if one the libraries was missing. Even if you include `@angular/core` in the `packages.json`, you'll get a message like `@angular/core is missing`.

In this case, reduce the version, maybe a previous version will do.

I got all these errors for Angular 13 and went back to Angular 12 and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Update Node to the latest version from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
2. Set `enableIvy: false` in `tsconfig.json`.
3. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.
4. Run `npm cache clean --force`.
5. Run `npm install`.

I recommend you to use `ng update` to find out outdated packages and update them all by running the `ng update @package` commands and then run `npm update` too.

Comment: Unfortunately, stackblitz does not give you the possibility to do all that. I've tried to disable ivy before and that gives me another error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5jspzl

Comment: yes I know. but the other error that I faced too is about your code not ngcc compilation. @JanosVinceller

Comment: Sorry, this did not help me, I posted my solution as an answer now.